# How to use the joins method with first_or_initialize instead of find_or_initialize_by (Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, inner-join

Is there a way to rewrite the process below, which currently uses `find_or_initialize_by`, using the `joins` method?

For context - I have `users` (employees) who record their `attendances` in the system (a `user` has many `attendances`, and an `attendance` record belongs to a `user`).

```rb
Attendance.find_or_initialize_by(
  user: User.find_by(name: 'Bob'),
  date: Time.zone.today
)
.update(...) # Update some columns after this
```

I'm trying to rewrite it using `.joins` like this:

```rb
Attendance.joins(:user)
  .where(users: {name: 'Bob'}, date: Time.zone.today)
  .first_or_initialize
  .update(...) # Update some columns after this
```

My tests come back with mixed results:

- Test cases where the record only needs to be `updated` pass
- Test cases where the `attendance` record doesn't exist yet (i.e. cases when I have to `initialize`) fail

The error message is
`ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: User must exist`.
But I'm confused because the user actually exists - if I debug using `byebug`, the user is there.

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using?

Comment: Also, this may just be your example code and not the actual problem, but you have `user: ` in  your first example and `users:` in your second. If Attendance `belongs_to` User, this doesn't seem correct.

Comment: I’m using 2.6.2. Let me check your other point later, thanks for the comment!

Comment: Do you mean Ruby 2.6.2 (current) or Rails 2.6.2 (very ancient)?

Comment: @Beejamin Sorry, I somehow misread your comment earlier! I’m using Ruby 2.6.2 and Rails 5.2.3.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than starting from the Attendance model, I would tend to start from the User, like this:

`User.find_by(name: 'Bob').attendances.find_or_initialize_by(date: Time.zone.today).update(...)`

That keeps things easy to read. You could add an association extension method to make things more convenient:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attendances do
    def for_date(date)
      find_or_initialize_by(date: Time.zone.today)
    end
  end
end

# Then call with:
User.attendances.for_date(Time.zone.today)
```

Depending on what you're doing with that attendance record, you could also have your `for_date` method take extra arguments.

<s>`first_or_initialize` has been removed according to: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html.</s> *Thanks to @engineersmnky for the correction. The method is undocumented, but that looks likes a mistake.*

Comment: `first_or_initialize_by` was never a method and both `find_or_initialize_by` and `first_or_initialize` are still viable

Comment: Thank you - edited. That said, I still can't find a reference to that method in the API docs at all - do you have a reference for it?

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L127

Comment: Thank you both. I realise it may be more natural to start from `User` and may end up doing so.

Answer (score -1):

Are you setting Bob's ID in the update call? Basically when you run this, and the where clause returns empty, an empty new record is instantiated. At this moment, all reference to Bob is gone, so you need to set it again in the update:

```
Attendance.joins(:user)
  .where(users: {name: 'Bob'}, date: Time.zone.today)
  .first_or_initialize
  .update(user: User.find_by(name: 'Bob'), #other stuff ) # Update some columns after this
```

Comment: You're right - if I run my test with `byebug` under the `.first_or_initialize` line and inspect the content, any reference to user Bob is gone.
`#<Attendance id: nil, user_id: nil, date: "2019-05-21", ... (other columns)>`
This seems odd to me because the `date` value has been set as it's supposed to. What causes this difference in behavior? Is it because I used the join query when specifying the user?

Comment: (In response to your first question: no, I wasn't setting Bob's ID in the `update` call.)

Comment: Basically what happens is that after the where returns an empty set, you are initializing, which is basically the same as running Model.new. So that’s why you lost the context of Bob and need to reassign. Which shouldn’t be a problem right? So it boils down to a matter of taste I guess, the find_or_create_by versus the double fetching of Bob. I think I personally like the first approach better.

Comment: I don't think my question was clear, so let me rephrase - you said the query returns an empty set, but in truth, the `date` column is filled while the `user` comes back empty (so the created record is only partially empty). What is the cause for the difference in behavior between `date` and `user`?

Comment: And I agree, I think I will ultimately go with the first approach. Just trying to learn about the different behavior for future reference :)

Comment: What happens when you put ‘user’ instead of ‘users’ in the where clause?

Comment: That returns this error: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "user"` (I'm using PostgreSQL).
I think this part has to be plural even if you're retrieving one user, judging from the example in the [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables):

`Client.joins(:orders).where(orders: { created_at: time_range })`

Comment: I think that the problem lies there, since you could join multiple users, so rails is unaware of which user to set in the new object.

Comment: Possible... but then that raises the question I raised in my original post; cases where the record only needs to be updated (not initialized) are fine. For example, if I tried to update some column of an already-existing attendance record, like this, it works: `Attendance.joins(:user).where(users: {name: 'Bob'}, date: Time.zone.today).first_or_initialize.update(some_column: some_value)`